# Can I use 'being drowned' in this kind of sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this grammatically correct?

> If I go closer I would die after being drowned into the sea

Answer (score 2):

If I go closer, I would die after being drowned into the sea.

The verb drown means die by being unable to breathe underwater. So the use of the verb die is superfluous in the sentence. You can simply say as follows:

If I go closer, I would drown in the sea.

However, if you want to mention the reason for death, you can use the preposition from/of after the verb die as follows.

......... I would die from/of drowning in the sea.